# C++ input and function issue (basics)

Tags: c++, function, input

I'm quite new to C++. In fact I started learning it today. So I wanted to mix a bit of what I grasped from the tutorials I've read and create a simple program that would print out a variable part of a function. The variable's value would be user supplied.

So far I'm up to here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

cin >> int x;

void number(int x)
{
    cout << "Number is: " << x << endl;
}

int main()
{
    number(x);
    return 0;
}
```

This however is experiencing errors. One of which is that the variable **x** is not declared in this scope.

Answer (score 2):

move "cin" in Main:

```
 int x;
  cin>>x;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code starts execution at the start of the main() function.  Right now

```
cin >> int x;
```

isn't being executed at all!  This means that once you get to

```
number(x);
```

the program hasn't heard of the variable "x" yet, and throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ the code of the main function must be in its paranthesis. And int x; must be before cin >>

```
int main()
{
  int x;
  cin >> x;
  number(x);
  return 0;
}
```